# How to make heartbeats for Autocad from a plugin (C#)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Im developping a plugin for AutoCAD on Forge. Via a custom command (Provided by the plugin), it will publish a big png (25000x20000 for example) and sometimes it causes a timeout and the workitem failed.

```
<report.txt>
...
[03/02/2022 22:10:41] Save changes to page setup [Yes/No]? <N> N
[03/02/2022 22:10:41] Proceed with plot [Yes/No] <Y>: Y
[03/02/2022 22:10:41] Effective plotting area:  21212.94 wide by 20000.00 high
[03/02/2022 22:10:41] Plotting viewport 2.
[03/02/2022 22:11:42] Error: AutoCAD Core Console is shut down due to timeout.
[03/02/2022 22:11:42] End script phase.
[03/02/2022 22:11:42] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
...
```

Im guessing the timeout will be done by design [(Work Item Heartbeat)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/rate-limits/da-rate-limits/) but havent succeed to find the way to make the long plotting survive.

Is there anyone who can help me?

The suggested solution, [HeartBeat.cs](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/design.automation.inventor-utilities/blob/master/Solution/DesignAutomationInventorUtilities/HeartBeat.cs) has been tried but it seems not working for my case (because the engine Im using is AutoCAD?) though the document said that it will be ok if my plugin will print something (to stdout(=report.txt?) or trace(the suggested one) before one minute silence.

Additionally the actual `PLOT` command is issued on a scr file which is loaded and is executed inside my plugin.

PS1.
The only way to print something on report.txt I find is

```
Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
doc.Editor.WriteMessage("somthing");
```

and seems the `doc` doesnt work with threading.

PS2.
The `limitProcessingTimeSec` for the workitem has been changed to 300, but it seems not related.

Comment: May be can you share your workitem Id ? or script that I can try at my end .. Do you have any ballpark estimate how much time does it take if you run on accoreconsole locally ?

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala Thank you for your help. I have post the failing one few mins ago and its workitemId is `4e4c0ef4a9d44efc8989b827c40b69bf` and Im not sure how log it'd take if it'd be done locally now but my guess is less than 3 mins.